# Проблемы с обработкой ответа на запрос VK SDK

Tags: android, vkontakte-api, sdk

Всем привет! Прошу помощи.
Есть следующий код(для примера):

```
                final VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get();
                request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                        super.onComplete(response);

                        //Log.v("VK SDK",response.json.toString());

                        VKApiUser user = (VKApiUser) response.parsedModel;

                        if (user==null){Log.v("Ошибка","Ничего не загрузилось");}
                        else {
                            Log.v("User name:", user.first_name + user.last_name);
                        }
```

Исходя из примеров на github, параметр response необходимо привести к нужному классу. Но при исполнении прилетает ошибка:

```
01-08 09:31:47.233    1545-1545/com.vksdk.avsidorov.testvksdk V/VK SDK﹕ {"response":[{"last_name":"User last name","id":20***,"first_name":"User first name"}]}
01-08 09:31:47.233    1545-1545/com.vksdk.avsidorov.testvksdk D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-08 09:31:47.233    1545-1545/com.vksdk.avsidorov.testvksdk W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d86b20)
01-08 09:31:47.233    1545-1545/com.vksdk.***.testvksdk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vksdk.***.testvksdk, PID: 1545
    java.lang.ClassCastException: com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKList cannot be cast to com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiUser
```

Что делать, куда копать?

Comment: @Sidik211, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ну очевидно же...

> com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKList cannot be cast to com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiUser

Означает, что вам в `VKResponse response` приходит не `VKApiUser`, а `VKList`  
Тем более, что запрашиваете вы не пользовател***я***, а пользовател***ей***:

```
VKApi.users().get();
```

Вам в ответ и приходит список (`VKList`) из пользователей (`VKApiUser`).  
А надо всего лишь научиться **читать**...

Comment: Там момент в том, что при отсутствии параметров возвращается данные по текущему пользователю(по одному):
{"response":[{"last_name":"User last name","id":20***,"first_name":"User first name"}

P.S. метода VKApi.user().get() нет как такового.

Comment: @Sidik211, ну, и? Вы не знаете, как проверить, к какому классу относится тот или иной объект?

Comment: @metalurgus, не совсем улавливаю зачем? То, что приходит VKList, а не VKApiUser понятно и из лога. Я предполагаю, что я скорее неверно обрабатываю response. Но, считаю, что вряд ли в данном случае предполагалась "прокладка" в виде дополнительного объекта VKList.

Comment: @Sidik211, все-таки надо научиться читать. По крайней мере [документацию][1]...    

> Результат     
> После успешного выполнения
> возвращает массив объектов
> пользователей.

  [1]: http://vk.com/dev/users.get

Comment: @metalurgus, благодарю за помощь. Понимаю, что мне в данном случае возвращается массив из одного элемента. Вместе с тем, к сожалению, не получилось разобраться, что с ним делать дальше((
Не вижу в классе VKApiUsers методов для обращения к отдельным элементам.

P.S. Ориентировался в большей степени на документацию к SDK http://vkcom.github.io/vk-android-sdk/